# Notification is slowing down

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications

In my application I am download files using intent service. While download starts a download progress notification is also created. Everything works fine, but the problem is that the notification slows down the phone: The following is my code:
Note: I have removed non related part of the code to make simple and clear:

```
public void startDownload(String name, String packageName, String path, boolean obb, boolean data) {
    try {
        notificationId = generateNoficationId(packageName);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadListView.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(name)
                    .setContentText("downloading...")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.newiconpurple)
                    .setContentInfo("0%")
                    .setProgress(100, 0, true)
                    .setContentIntent(pi)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notification = mBuilder.build();
            startForeground(notificationId, notification);

            url = new URL(IPClass.SERVERIP + path + "/" + packageName);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(7000);
            long fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadtmp/" + packageName, true);
            byte dataSize[] = new byte[16384];
            int count;
            downloadedSoFar = 0;
            continueDownload = true;
            while ((count = input.read(dataSize)) > 0 && continueDownload) {
                if (!downloadCancelList.contains(packageName)) {
                    downloadedSoFar = downloadedSoFar + count;
                    output.write(dataSize, 0, count);
                    progress = (int) ((downloadedSoFar * 100L) / fileLength);
                    progressChange(name, progress, packageName, obb, data);
                } else {
                    continueDownload = false;
                    int startId = downloadIdList.get(packageName);
                    stopSelf(startId);
                    nm.cancel(notificationId);
                    downloadCancelList.remove(packageName);
                    stopForeground(true);
                }
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        nm.cancel(notificationId);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) output.close();
            if (input != null) input.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {

        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        } else if (resumeConnection != null) {
            resumeConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

And the following is the progressChange method:

```
   void progressChange(final String name, final int progress, final String packageName, boolean obb, boolean data) {

        if (lastupdate != progress) {
            lastupdate = progress;
            if (progress < 100) {

                mBuilder.setProgress(100, Integer.valueOf(progress), false).setContentInfo(progress + "%");
                nm.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());

            } else if (progress == 100) {
                stopForeground(true);
                mBuilder.setContentText("download finished").setProgress(0, 0, false).setOngoing(false).setContentInfo("");
                nm.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
                new DownloadController().removeFromDownloadList(packageName);
                new DownloadFinished(name, packageName, obb, data).execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad idea to send notification so many times. Each notification needs to be inflated, stored and displayed. Inflated notifications aren't removed from memory instantly when removed from screen. You'r just creating huge stack of Views that occupies RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you be more specific

Comment: Well, for example, only sent a notification each time the progress has progressed by a full 10%

Comment: Count how many times you update your notification. I bet you have ~100 updates. So view, that displayed in notification must be inflated (don't really know if it inflates or changes directly, bet on first). So image creating some view 100 times, it'll really go wrong after 50 I think. To test - just open simple activity and start rotating screen, when look at memory profiler. Values will increase until GC(if no leaks). 

So change progress less often. Like every 10% or what.

Comment: Currently each 1% the progress is updated! don't you think something like 10% is too much!

Comment: @Shoaib just experiment with values and look at memory profiler. In Google example they use 5%

Comment: One thing else i have noticed that the problem does not belong to progress change but it belongs to the notification itself. Because as soon as the notification appears the phone slows down and so does the notification bar

Comment: @Shoaib try to remove drawable. Also, is that code run in background?

Comment: The code runs in an intentService. The onHandleIntent method calls startDownload method.

Comment: Remove whole notification and run code. I think, that problem isn't in notification, but in download code. If yes, you'll need to fix it.

Comment: Ohhhhhh Ekalips you are right! The problem is with the image in the drawable. The image size very huge! Thanks